# Node.js Best way to load JS variable synchronously

Tags: javascript, json, performance, node.js

I want to load some data in server.js file that is stored in /data/projects.js (or .json depending on the answer of the question).

I see two possibilities:

1. using readFileSync:

   ```
   function readJsonFileSync() {
       var file = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/data/projects.json', 'utf8');
       return JSON.parse(file);
   }
   ```

   and projects.json being a traditional json file
2. using require:

   ```
   function readJsonFileReq() {
       return require('./data/projects.js')['projects'] ;
   }
   ```

   with projects.js containing:

   ```
   exports.projects = {
        // My variable
   };
   ```

Question is which one is the best:

- in terms of performance?
- in terms of node writability/philosophy? (eg. require() being reserved for modules)

I would guess solution 2 is better since require() is probably optimised for reading JS code, whereas solution 1 has to read the file, and then parse it, but parsing it may be cheaper than executing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules ,

> .js files are interpreted as JavaScript text files, and .json files are parsed as JSON text files. .node files are interpreted as compiled addon modules loaded with dlopen.

So I'd do `require("./data/projects.json")` since it's the shortest, and presumably optimized quite well.

Laurent makes a good remark: result of require is cached. This can be an advantage or disadvantage. If you read the file only one time when your app starts, it doesn't matter.

This is how node does it (aside from caching the result):

```
Module._extensions['.json'] = function(module, filename) {
 var content = NativeModule.require('fs').readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
 try {
  module.exports = JSON.parse(stripBOM(content));
 } catch (err) {
   err.message = filename + ': ' + err.message;
   throw err;
 }
};
```

https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/module.js#L479

Answer (score 3):

The main reason to use sync fs functions in node.js is load files before your app starts. The most common reason being to load a config file. In this case, performance doesn't matter.

That being said, the main difference between `readFileSync` and `require` is that require will cache the content of the file. I've seen countless times `require` being used to load a json file, so I don't think that it's reserved to modules (be sure to include `.json` in the file path, though).

Finally, don't forget that you can use `module.exports = {..}` if you want to write `var projects = require('./data/projects.js');`.

**EDIT**: For reference, I checked node.js's source code, and as suspected, `require` uses `readFileSync` internally:

https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/module.js#L472

```
// Native extension for .js
Module._extensions['.js'] = function(module, filename) {
  var content = NativeModule.require('fs').readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
  module._compile(stripBOM(content), filename);
};
```

Comment: I usually wrap my per-environment external config file in a module that manages default values, system variables, etc. so I use both `require` *and* `readFileSync`